# Show similar category portfolio items?

Tags: plugins, custom-taxonomy

I have a portfolio with categories. Portfolio-Items have featured image and are assigned to one category.

Now when that Portfolio-Item is displayed, I want to display all other Portfolio-Items of that same category only next to it with its featured image.

This line of code prints my current category:

```
 echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'portfolio_category', 'Cat: ', ', ', '' );
```

I want to show the featured image of that category only.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

I would create a new `WP_Query` instance, using a Taxonomy parameter as follows:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query([
    'post_type'       => '<custom_post_type>',
    '<taxonomy_slug>' => '<term_slug>',
    'fields'          => 'ids', // We just need the post IDs
    // Add other query parameters as needed
]);
```

[More on using Taxonomy parameters in a `WP_Query` instance](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

Then, I would loop through the posts and get the post thumbnail as follows:

```
$post_thumbnails = [];

foreach ($wp_query->posts as $post_id) {
    $post_thumbnails[$post_id] = get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id[, $size = 'post-thumbnail', $attr = NULL]); // Notice the optional arguments
}
```

[More on the `get_the_post_thumbnail()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail)

Then all you need to do is loop through the thumbnails and display them.

(You'll probably also want more information associated with the post than just the post ID and it's thumbnail, so you might want to restructure the query to return more than just the ID.)

Hopefully that answers your question. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. But I am still new to WordPress development so its taking me time to implement what you just said. Hopefully it works.